# FFT plot in Matlab, accuracy

Tags: matlab, fft

I have a small input signal of 60Hz sine wave from signal generator, which is corrupted with 50Hz mains supply frequency. I want to measure the amplitude of the 60Hz signal using FFT because it is very small to see in the oscilloscope.
The Matlab FFT code:

```
y = data;    
Fs = 2048;
[r, L] = size(y);
NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L); % Next power of 2 from length of y
Y = fft(y,NFFT)/L;
f = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);
% Plot single-sided amplitude spectrum.
plot(f,2*abs(Y(1:NFFT/2+1)))
```

But the FFT plot doesn't give a sharp peak at 50 and 60Hz. The plot looks like this: [image: zoomed]. The consecutive points have high and low amplitude alternatively which gives a saw-tooth like plot. Why is it so? Is the amplitude of 60Hz affected by this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phenomenon you see is called "window effect" or also "[spectral leakage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_leakage)". It occurs because ideally you would like to analyze an infinitely long signal (which would give you ideal peaks in the frequency domain), but actually you analyze a truncated (windowed) signal. In fact you multiply your signal with a window function - in your case a simple rectangular window - which in the frequency domain corresponds to a convolution with the frequency response of the window. This gives you the effect that you see. You can try different [window functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function), but you will not get rid of the basic effect.

BTW, for the plot you could try using values in dB, i.e. use $20\log (|Y|)$ instead of a linear plot; this will make things look a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

If the 50 or 60 Hz signals aren't at frequencies whose periods are exact sub-multiples of the FFT length, then you will see  the effects of the rectangular windowing of your data.

It is also possible that your 50 Hz signal is not a perfectly pure sinusoid, and thus you will see the sidebands due to the modulations of the center frequency.